# Reverse php vertical bar chart

Tags: php, html, css

index.php

```
<?php
$Dpoint = 80;
$Ipoint = 70;
$Hpoint = 60;
$Apoint = 90;
$max = 250; // max point 250;
$percent = 100; //set 100 percent;
$scale = 4.0; //

if ( !empty($max) ) {
 $Dpercent = ($Dpoint * $percent) / $max;
 $Ipercent = ($Ipoint * $percent) / $max;
 $Hpercent = ($Hpoint * $percent) / $max;
 $Apercent = ($Apoint * $percent) / $max;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <label><strong>A</strong></label><div class="bar"><div style="height:<?php echo round($Dpercent * $scale); ?>px;"></div></div><p><?php echo("{$Dpercent}%"."<br />");?></p>
    <label><strong>B</strong></label><div class="bar"><div style="height:<?php echo round($Ipercent * $scale); ?>px;"></div></div><p><?php echo("{$Ipercent}%"."<br />");?></p>
    <label><strong>C</strong></label><div class="bar"><div style="height:<?php echo round($Hpercent * $scale); ?>px;"></div></div><p><?php echo("{$Hpercent}%"."<br />");?></p>
    <label><strong>D</strong></label><div class="bar"><div style="height:<?php echo round($Apercent * $scale); ?>px;"></div></div><p><?php echo("{$Apercent}%"."<br />");?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.bar{
    margin:auto;
    background: grey;
    width: 16px;
    /*margin: 0 0 5px 10px;*/
    padding: 1px;
    height: 400px;
    float:left;
}

.bar div{
    background-color: #00aeef;
    height: 16px;
}
```

i am trying to make vertical bar chart , but the blue bar is up to down , how do reverse it ? so what i mean is the blue bar start at below.

i cant seem to make the text down there also , cant anyone help me make the bar looks more alike ? and reverse the blue bar ?

Comment: This looks more like HTML/CSS question - you could make a plain HTML/CSS [code snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) out of it to make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure how you want it, but those bars are from bottom upwards. The key is to use proper `position` setting and coordinates.

```css
.bar{
    background: grey;
    width: 16px;
    padding: 1px;
    height: 160px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bar div{
  background-color: #00aeef;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1px;
  width: 16px;
  left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"><div style="height:80px;"></div></div>
<div class="bar"><div style="height:120px;"></div></div>
<div class="bar"><div style="height:12px;"></div></div>
<div class="bar"><div style="height:150px;"></div></div>
```

Comment: thank you , you are the best !! is all i wanted , but one more simple question if i have text how to i put them all into right side? i edit your code , can you please check it out ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you want to do. Put text inside the bars?